# List of Unicode version support by macOS version

Tags: macos, unicode

I'm looking for a list of supported Unicode versions by MacOS version. Does such a list exist?

To be specific: I like to understand which code points and code blocks are supported in the "Character Viewer", even if no font is available that contains all codepoints.

For example, on macOS High Sierra, the codeblock for Maya numerals (codepoints U+1D2E0 and up) is missing, which was introduced in Unicode version 11. Unsurprisingly, as High Sierra was released in September 2017 and Unicode 11 in June 2018.

So far, I have not found any such list, only specification of the underlying file systems:

- The APFS filesytems supports all codepoints in Unicode 9, and is ignorant of codepoint normalization.
- HFS plus filesystem supports any codepoint, but performs (the somewhat uncommon) decomposition normalization (NFD). Unicode 2.1 decomposition up till Mac OS X 10.2, and Unicode 3.2 decomposition starting with Mac OS X 10.3.

Comment: I'm also interested in this question. For example I want to use the parachute character  from Unicode 12.0 (which was introduced in 2019) on macOS 10.14.6 "Mojave" (which was introduced June 2018), but it doesn't appear to render there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any list of the type you mention, but at least some MacOS  apps will display anything in Unicode for which a font is installed regardless of whether Character Viewer is up to date or not.  My High Sierra TextEdit and Safari can display Mayan Numerals once the Babelstone font for them is installed.

[image]